# call Lambda ARN from MySql (RDS Aurora)

Tags: mysql, aws-lambda, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

Can we call a Lambda ARN only with a simple statement to test from RDS Aurora (Workbench Mysql)?

```
CALL mysql.lambda_async('arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:00000000000000:function:Test00000000','')
```

On running above I get below error. There is no JSON payload, I wan to call a Lambda ARN which just sends an email directly.

```
14:33:18    CALL mysql.lambda_async('arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:0000000000000000:function:Test00000000','')    
Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query  30.000 sec
```

Comment: The default wait timeout in mysql is 30 seconds, if your call needs more time you have to increase it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the error was that Lambda was not receiving all the information from the stored procedure. Out of 6 expected values it was getting all 6 but in different order, which confused the function taking long time.Once all was queued in sequence it worked fine and pretty quick.